# Gwt Tomcat Deploy : Just Does Nothing

Tags: gwt, tomcat7

if I deploy my project to the Tomcat server which uses just client side code , it works perfectly.

But if my project has a server side code , for example, a button which uses RPC , when i clicked the button, project does nothing at all. No Warnings, no errors etc. Just does nothing at all.

And also, when I deploy "the default GWT example ( greetings project )" to the Tomcat server, it doesn't work.
( I mean my problem is not related with my project's code )

p.s. : My project works perfectly in the Dev Mode.

Could you help me please?

Comment: What happens if you run in DevMode in [`-noserver` mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT's) against your Tomcat server?

Comment: install firebug, check if clicking a button is sending a request to the server and what is in the response

Answer (score 1):

Let us say, wWhen you run on dev mode, your URL was

> localhost:port#/page1.

And that the war file name is happy.

Therefore, when you deploy to Tomcat, the server no longer serves it as localhost:port#/page1.

Your app would now be served as

> localhost:port#/happy/page1

In your rpc remote service interface file you would have specified the relative path as "/page1".

However, you have to check your web.xml and make sure the servlets are specified in relative paths as well. Check your web.xml to ensure the servlet paths are not hard-coded to

> localhost:port#/page1.